# Matriz em C aparecendo números grandes e não os digitados

Tags: c, array, matriz

Estou com um problema em pelo menos todas as minhas matrizes feitas em sala de aula, até cheguei a pegar um problema corrigido da internet e minha matriz no PC ainda está aparecendo números aleatórios.

[image: Resultado]

o código é o seguinte :

```
void main (void){

int matriz[3][3], i, j, rot[3][3];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
            printf("Digite o valor da matriz[%i][%i]: ",i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%i", &matriz[j]);
        }
    }
    //mostrando a matriz inicial
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
            printf(" %i ", matriz[j]);
        }
    }
    //rotacionando a matriz
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        if(i==0){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                rot[j][2]=matriz[j];
            }
        }
        if(i==1){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                rot[j][1]=matriz[j];
            }
        }
        if(i==2){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                rot[j][0]=matriz[j];
            }
        }
    }
    //mostrando a matriz rotacionada
    printf("\nMATRIZ 90º\n");

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
            printf(" %i ", rot[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O maior problema é que está manipulando uma matriz como um vetor, simplesmente abandonou as colunas, se é uma matriz em todo momento tem que ter dois índices, um de linha e outro de coluna, e não tendo dois vai pegar lixo. O código está confuso e complexo demais.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int matriz[3][3], rot[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("Digite o valor da matriz[%d][%d]: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) printf(" %d ", matriz[i][j]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) for (int j = 2; j >= 0; j--) rot[i][j] = matriz[j][2 - i];
    printf("\nMATRIZ 90º");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) printf(" %d ", rot[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gv2c2r). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/RotateMatrix90). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/RotateMatrix90.c).